Please help me identify a diode
Good day,
I can't seem to find any information about this diode/component. It measures 53.7 Ohms and only 25 mV on diode junction test. Would you please be able to help me identify what it is and whether it is blown? What replacement shall I order? Thank you.

I can clearly see 8804 in the picture which is probably the device code. From the picture there is also some partially visible text which might be GI. Can you clarify what the other text is. GI might mean this is a General Instrument  device.

8804 could be a date code (4th week of 1988). GI is almost surely the manufacturer. Measurements made in-circuit are almost worthless. Similarly, reading the part number may not prove useful unless  you can see all the markings.

It could be a Zener or other special purpose diode.
If you have a similar board, clip one lead, measure forward and backward voltage drop with constant-current power supply limited to a mA or two, and resolder the break (far easier than unsoldering one lead from a multilayer PCB). From that data, you could find a replacement.
Better would be to mention the make and model of the device  with that PCB, and find a schematic diagram.
